# How to store images out of meteor project on live server but access them from web

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have a small meteor project for image library. I have 100K images to be already uploaded on server and use them in my project.

when create a bundle with images inside `/public/img/` folder, all resource entries are present inside `bundle\programs\web.browser\program.json` which makes it ~40MB. when I try to start server live on VPS server, it does not start unfortunately.

So I need suggestion how to manage these images to be accessed from web using meteor?

> **NOTE** : I already know little about S3 storage, But I want to keep is simple and only on my server.

Comment: separate the storage server from application server. you can use AWS S3 for this

Comment: Are you sure you want those 100K images to be processed and included into bundle every time you build your project?

Comment: Have you looked at cloudinary? AWS cloudfront might also be a good alternative. An image-heavy site can really benefit from a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Using S3 doesn't have to be complicated. You can set it up quickly and it will solve the issue you are having.

I'd recommend you read [this great article](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/uploading-files-to-amazon-s3) by The Meteor Chef to find out how to use S3!